# Convert MD5 representation to hex in C++

Tags: c++, hex, md5

I have an MD5 string which i am converting to hex. Is there a better way to do this? I currently am doing:

```
unsigned char digest[16]; 
string result;
char buf[32];
for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
{
   sprintf_s(buf, "%02x", digest[i]);
   result.append( buf );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This version should be faster. If you need more speed, change `string result` to `char` array.

```cpp
static const char hexchars[] = "0123456789abcdef";

unsigned char digest[16];
string result;

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    unsigned char b = digest[i];
    char hex[3];

    hex[0] = hexchars[b >> 4];
    hex[1] = hexchars[b & 0xF];
    hex[2] = 0;

    result.append(hex);
}
```

Comment: this one works - only answer here that correctly processes by nibbles.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it seems like doing the conversion yourself may be easier than using `sprintf_s` (or something similar) to do it for you. If possible I'd also use a container for the input instead of a raw array.

```
std::string to_hex(std::vector<unsigned char> const &digest) { 
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";

    string result;

    for (int i=0; i<digest.size(); i++) {
        result += digits[digest[i] / 16];
        result += digits[digest[i] % 16];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using streams:

```
std::string base_64_encode(const unsigned char *bytes, const size_t byte_count)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::setfill('0') << std::hex;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < byte_count; ++i)
        oss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(bytes[i]);

    return oss.str();
}
```

Use like this:

```
std::string encoded = base_64_encode(digest, 16);
```

Probably not the most performant solution though.

Answer (score -1):

```
unsigned char digest[16];
// (...)
string result;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(digest); ++i) {
    result += (digest[i] >= 10) ? (digest[i] + 'a' - 10) : (digest[i] + '0');
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. The loop assumes it is iterating over each hex digit (4 bits), when it is in fact iterating over each bytes (two hex digits)